# CN1 parse.h not found

Tags: codenameone, parse4cn1

I'm trying to use the **parse4cn1** library but upon sending an **iOS** build to the server, I get the following error:

> /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build9107748602253278046xxx/dist/MCGMain-src/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.m:39:9:
>   fatal error: 'Parse.h' file not found

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the cocoapod build hints as described in the documentation?

https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1/wiki/Setting-Up-Push-For-iOS#adding-the-parse-ios-sdk-to-your-app